# How to connect 2 different spinners altogether

Tags: android, listener, spinner

I am trying to connect 2 spinners together. Meaning, the items inside 2nd spinner will depend on whatever item is chosen for the 1st spinner.

This is the code inside the main java file.

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
        this, R.array.planets_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

}

This is the code inside MyOnItemSelectedListener.java

public class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
    View view, int pos, long id) {
  Toast.makeText(parent.getContext()), "The planet is " +
      parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
  // Do nothing.
}
```

}

So the onItemSelected function will print out the item that was chosen in 1st spinner on the screen. However, I can't figure out how to create the 2nd spinner fully based on the value inside 1st spinner.

I know that there should be something needed to be done inside onItemSelected, but I just can't figure it out since I am a newbie in Java Android.

Can you guys assist me on this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just do something very similar to what you do in onCreate, only with the other spinner.  For example:

```
List<String> values = findValuesBySelection(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString());
Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
        this, values, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner2.setAdapter(adapter);
```